Code runs but only I change the out put type from class library, to different output type, and then back to class
I am working on creating an ASP.NET webpage on .NET 4.8 framework. When I first launch my code from Visual Studio, I get a server error in '/' application stating:

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /default.aspx

However, while fidgeting around, I discovered that when I opened up properties, went to the output type, and changed it from class library, to a different output type, then back to class library the code runs perfectly.
To me I don't understand how changing the output type back and forth changes anything so I'm not sure what to fix to make the code run right on its own.

What is your Visual Studio version and what kind of project you created?
